# Apply css to all but one element with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to make the background of my mobile navigation to be opacity 0.5

I am using this:

```
$('body:not(#navigation-mobile)').css({opacity: '0.5'});
```

However, the whole body turns to that opacity when i want all but the `#navigation-mobile` to.

Comment: There's only one `body` element (I hope!) in your markup, so if you make it's opacity .5, the _whole page_ will be .5 - so do you instead want to make all _elements_ except the nav .5 opacity?  If so, you're probably looking for something like `$('body > *:not(#navigation-mobile)').css('opacity': '.5');`.... Or, are you truly looking to make the background have opacity?

Comment: opacity on an element apply to all its content, so what you have in mind won't work

Comment: Do you have an example of your general HTML structure? There are plenty of selector options you can use for this (not body though) but nobody will be able to give you an accurate answer without more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity effects all children of the applied element. To get around it, set your background as its own element with no children and apply opacity to only the background. You will likely have to use something like this on the background container:

```
 position: fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:1; width:100vw; height:100vh;
```

The content container will then sit on top by also giving it:

```
 position: fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:10;
```

You can then apply opacity to your background without impacting the content. Do not apply the background to the body. Make a separate div and apply it to that div.

Comment: I think what OP is saying is that they want to lower the opacity on everything except the navigation. This can probably be done without an extra element, just more accurate selector(s). I was confused by the wording at first too.

Comment: This works except for the fact that the new background element doesn't respond to the opacity. If i do the opacity to the content container it works but not for the background.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to give you a specific solution without a sample of your HTML, but the comments are correct that applying opacity to the `body` will affect everything that lives inside it.

Assuming your structure is similar to the following:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <nav id="navigation-mobile"></nav>
  <main></main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

you can do something like:

```
$('body > *:not(#navigation-mobile)').css({'opacity': 0.5 })
```

You'll need to adjust the selector depending on your markup, but the general idea is that you use the `:not()` selector to apply the opacity to your mobile navigation's siblings, which will then apply the opacity to their children. If, for example, you have a container wrapping all of your content, you can replace `body` in the selector with your container class/ID.

If you edit your question with relevant HTML I can edit my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove the opacity for a child-element [[1]](https://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/)

So what if you instead make the rest of the page, except for the navigational bar, to one element.

Like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="navigation-mobile">
    <ul class="inline-list">
      <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="body">
    <div id="header">blabla</div>
    <div id="content">blabla</div>
    <div id="footer">blabla</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In this way you can only use this jquery code:

```
$('#body').css({opacity: '0.5'});
```

And the navigational bar will remain it's full opacity.